# Delete Duplicate And Merge Data In One cell in html format in MS Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, outlook

When I click button on MS Access form, it will display data in the below format in MS OUtlook in table format...Data is getting from tables.

```
ID - Name - Year    - Fname - Product
1 -  XYZ  - Feb2011 - John  - p1
1 -  XYZ  - Feb2011 - John  - p2
1 -  XYZ  - Feb2011 - Ken   - p3
1 -  XYZ  - Feb2011 - Ken   - p4
```

Instead of above format, i want to display data in below format. All (-) places should be replace with rows & columns.

```
ID - Name - Year    - Fname -  Product
1  - XYZ  - Feb2011 - John  -  p1
   -      -         -       -  p2
   -      -         - Ken   -  p3
   -      -         -       -  p4
```

Comment: You might want to try reformatting your example data. Without seeing any of your code, it's difficult to make any suggestion about what changes you should make.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's very dificult to do in a form.

But, you can try to do it in a report easily.
Design a report as usual. Then for each field, you can set the HideDuplicates property to true.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your version of Office you need to use MSWord as the editor for the email.  Then you can create a table and insert your data in it.  This is because all the functions of Word are then available to you.

You can do this still from Access.  What I suggest is that you learn first how to do the table etc in Word.  In word you can record a macro and then see the resulting code.  This is going to give you about 80% of the code you need.  Then you need to deal with your loop through your record set, adding a new line to your table each time.

Comment: -1 for the recommendation to use Word as email editor. Word as email editor is the source of all sorts of bugs and problems in Outlook that could be avoided if it weren't pushed as the default option.

Comment: David - thank you for your comment.  Until Microsoft agrees with you and removes it from Outlook as an option, may I suggest you point out your opinion to the questioner but not evaluate my opinion.

Comment: The questioner is going to be able to record macros in word much better then trying to get him up to date with maybe HTML which is probable his other option.

Comment: The problem is that youre recommendation may resolve the particular problem here, but has such bad side effects as to be a terrible choice. Of course, likely Word is already the email editor, as that's the default...

Comment: Not only is Word probably the default - it is the ONLY editor in Outlook 2007 and 2010 from what I understand.  IE was removed so even if you want to write HTML you will write it with Word.

Comment: Well, I would argue you shouldn't be writing email in HTML, but that boat sailed long ago...